# PhpStorm can't resolve @ionic/angular

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, phpstorm, ionic4

I've got an Ionic v4 project that is running fine, but PhpStorm cannot find my references to @ionic.

[image: cannot resolve symbol NavController]

It looks like the code is actually in the `/dist` directory, so if I change the reference to:

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular/dist'
```

PhpStorm doesn't complain and I get code completion features for @ionic/angular.

However, when running `ng serve` the project won't compile and I get errors in the console:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic/angular/dist'
```

**How can I fix this?**

Why does project compile when not specifying `/dist`?

---

Edit:

In PhpStorm, the entire node_modules directory is excluded, but not specifically the `@ionic/angular`.  Note, references to other modules are working fine.

[image: excluded directories]

Edit 2:
Here's how the folder coloring shows up:

[image: folder coloring]

- `@ionic/angular` doesn't work
- `@ionic-native/core` works
- `@angular/core` works

Comment: What PhpStorm version do you use? Please check that `node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist` folder is not marked excluded

Comment: @lena thanks for the response.  My version is a bit old, 2016.2.2.  Also, I just posted a screenshot of my directories.  The entire node_modules folder is excluded.  should this be a problem?  Other dependencies work fine.

Comment: your version is very old indeed. The entire node_modules folder is excluded by design - it's done for better performance. But direct dependencies listed in package.json should still be indexed. Please check what color is used for `node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist` folder in the **Project** tool window

Comment: @lena, I just added a screenshot showing how some of the folder coloring shows up.  I'll look at package.json files to see if I notice anything. Thanks.

Comment: actually, I'd suggest upgrading your PHPstorm version;  2016.2.2 doesn't support ionic 4

Comment: Thanks @lena; I've verified that the newer version of PHPstorm does not have this problem, but since I'm not ready to upgrade at the moment, I'm using the below workaround.  Thanks again for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share the workaround that I ended up using.

I just added an `index.d.ts` file in the `node_modules/@ionic/angular/` directory, with the following contents:

```
export * from './dist';
```

Of course it isn't ideal to modify the contents of your dependencies, but this simple fix keeps my IDE from driving me crazy... :-)